# Code coverage displays none

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I'm trying to write a test class for my following apex class:

```
public class KnowledgeArticleLookup {

   @InvocableMethod(label='Get Knowledge Articles' description='Gets knowledge article results')
   public static List<List<Response>> getMyArticles (List<Request> req){
    List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> Articles = new List<KnowledgeArticleVersion>();

    if(req[0].varType1 == 'Global Info'){
      if(req[0].varType2 == 'Location'){
            articles = [SELECT Id,
                              Title 
                             FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion 
                             WHERE PublishStatus='online' 
                             WITH DATA CATEGORY 
                             Global_Knowledge__c AT Location__c];
      }
    }
    List<List<Response>> outputResponse = new List<List<Response>>();
    List<Response> responses = new List<Response>();
    for(KnowledgeArticleVersion kav: articles) {
         Response response = new Response();
         response.articleversionId = kav.Id;
         response.articleTitle = kav.Title;
         responses.add(response);
    }
    outputResponse.add(responses);
   return outputResponse;
  }

  public class Request {
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
     public String varType1;
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
     public String varType2;
   }

   public class Response {
      @InvocableVariable
       public String articleversionId;
      @InvocableVariable
       public String articleTitle;
   }
}
```

My Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class KnowledgeKnowledgeLookupTest {
    
  static testMethod void getMyKnowledgesTest() {
    
   List<Knowledge__kav> articles = new List<Knowledge__kav>();
        
        Knowledge__kav Knowledgearticle = new Knowledge__kav();
        Knowledgearticle.Title = 'This is a test';
        Knowledgearticle.UrlName= 'Test';
        articles.add(Knowledgearticle);
        Insert articles;
  
        //Article Data Category setup
              list<Knowledge__DataCategorySelection> artdclist = new list<Knowledge__DataCategorySelection>();
            Knowledge__DataCategorySelection newArtDC = new Knowledge__DataCategorySelection();
            newArtDC.DataCategoryGroupName = 'Global_Knowledge';
            newArtDC.DataCategoryName = 'Location__c';
            newArtDC.ParentId = Knowledgearticle.id;
            artdclist.add(newArtDC);
 
        
             Knowledge__DataCategorySelection newArtDC1 = new Knowledge__DataCategorySelection();
            newArtDC1.DataCategoryGroupName = 'Global_Knowledge';
            newArtDC1.DataCategoryName = 'State';
            newArtDC1.ParentId = Knowledgearticle.id;
            artdclist.add(newArtDC1);
            
        
        insert artdclist;
        
             Knowledge__kav[]  articleKnowledge = [SELECT MasterVersionId, Id,ArticleNumber, Title,VersionNumber, OwnerId, LastPublishedDate, PublishStatus, ValidationStatus, KnowledgeArticleId FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE PublishStatus='online' with DATA CATEGORY Global_Knowledge__c AT Location__c];
            

         KnowledgeArticleLookup.getMyArticles(articleKnowledge);

                
         //System.assertEquals(articleKnowledge[0].Title, 'This is a test');
        System.assertEquals( 1 , articleKnowledge.size());
        System.assertEquals( True, articleKnowledge[0].Title == 'This is a test');
        
    }
    
}
```

However, when I run my test class, the code coverage in my apex class shows None and no % displayed.
Am I missing something?

After adding the following line of code:

```
KnowledgeArticleLookup.getMyArticles(articleKnowledge);
```

But I get this error message:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: `void getMyArticles(List<Knowledge__kav>)` from the type `KnowledgeArticleLookup`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a Request:

```
KnowledgeArticleLookup.Request[] requests = new KnowledgeArticleLookup.Request[0];
KnowledgeArticleLookup.Request request = new KnowledgeArticleLookup.Request();
request.varType1 = 'some value';
request.varType2 = 'some other value';
requests.add(request);
List<List<Response>> responses = KnowledgeArticleLookup.getMyArticles(requests);
// Assert responses here
```

The data types of the parameters must match in both type and quantity when calling a method.